# Direct proof of fact $u \in C(U)$ satisfies $|Du| \ge 1$ in sense of viscosity if and only if property holds

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, real-analysis

Is it possible anybody could sketch me a direct proof of the fact that $u \in C(U)$ satisfies $|Du| \ge 1$ in the sense of viscosity if and only if the following property holds?

If $V \subseteq U$ is open and bounded and $\varphi \in C^\infty(U)$ satisfies$$\begin{cases} |D\varphi| \le 1 & \text{in }V \\ \varphi \le u & \text{on }\partial V,\end{cases}$$then $\varphi \le u$ on $\overline{V}$.